# Angular - Error while building angular project for production

Tags: angular

While building an angular project for production it shows me an error. I am using Angular 5. 
[image]

I am not using `<template>` anywhere. I searched in a whole project it doesn't show

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3024 check this

Comment: Which version of bootstrap did you use ?

Comment: I am using `4.4.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make sure you have `ngx-bootstrap` v2+